# CustomValidationAttribute specifed method not being called

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I'm using the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidationAttribute to validate one of my POCO classes and when I try to unit test it, it's not even calling the validation method.

```
public class Foo
{
  [Required]
  public string SomethingRequired { get; set }
  [CustomValidation(typeof(Foo), "ValidateBar")]
  public int? Bar { get; set; }
  public string Fark { get; set; }

  public static ValidationResult ValidateBar(int? v, ValidationContext context) {
    var foo = context.ObjectInstance as Foo;
    if(!v.HasValue && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo.Fark)) {
      return new ValidationResult("Either Bar or Fark must have something in them.");
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

but when I try to validate it:

```
var foo = new Foo { 
  SomethingRequired = "okay"
};
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(foo, null, null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isvalid = Validator.TryValidateObject(foo, validationContext, validationResults);
Assert.IsFalse(isvalid); //FAIL!!! It's valid when it shouldn't be!
```

It never even steps into the custom validation method. What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the overload that takes a bool that specifies if all properties should be validated. Pass true for the last parameter.

```
public static bool TryValidateObject(
    Object instance,
    ValidationContext validationContext,
    ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults,
    bool validateAllProperties
)
```

If you pass false or omit the validateAllProperties, only the RequiredAttribute will be checked.
Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx).

Comment: The default value for this argument should have been true or this method should have a more explicit name.