# Custom Data-annotation not firing in unit-test

Tags: unit-testing, validation, data-annotations

I am currently experimenting with validation attributes, 
and now I am trying to validate my ViewModel which contains an EmailAddress with a custom validation attribute.

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public bool rememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I have made a unit-test where I give a false email address and try to validate my viewmodel.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestingInvalidEmailAddress()
{
    UserLoginModel model = new UserLoginModel();
    model = GetAValidLoginModel(); //Get a default-model where all parameters are correct
    model.email = "thisisnotavalidemail.com";

    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    bool validModel= Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results);
    //This is always true

    Assert.IsFalse(validModel);
}
```

The result of this test is always False.

So I checked my attribute, because I thought I might have made a mistake:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Email()
{
    string email;
    var attr = new EmailAddressAttribute();

    email = "myemail@domain.com";            
    Assert.IsTrue(attr.IsValid(email));

    email = "thisisnotavalidemail.com";
    Assert.IsFalse(attr.IsValid(email)); //If this fails, the test is successfull
}
```

And that did pass the test, using the exact same email address.

And when I test it in my browser, it also validates correctly.

So why does it not tell me that my email address is invalid in the first test-method?

Comment: Hmm, you mention 'custom' validation attributes. are you saying the [EmailAddress] attribute is not the .NET attribute?

Comment: No, I am using .NET4.0, the EmailAddress is only standard in .NET4.5.

Comment: mkay, because I tried the same thing with the .net attribute. **exact** same problem. the weird thing is, the [Required] attribute *does* work as expected.

Comment: I just gave it another shot, and I found this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165143) and that worked. I can't believe I didn't found this earlier. I just missed an extra parameter

Comment: Ah lol :) good stuff. Already upvoted cant do much more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165143).
Apparently I am just missing an extra parameter.

```
bool validModel= Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, **true**);
```