# Domain logic in a Entity framework Attribute

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've an ASP.NET MVC project with a domain and a data layer (contains just EF and migrations).

Now, I have to validate a Client's VATNumber field with a specific formula I'm having doubts where to place it.

I would like to use the Controller's ModelState to check if the field is valid, using a EF DataAnnotation ValidationAttribute, so I don't have to validate it in the Controller's Saving Method. But I'm conflicted having to put business logic in the data layer.

Is there some kind of alternative to ValidationAttribute, so it can be "injected"? Or I'm just looking at this wrongly?

Comment: [CustomValidationAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10165143/861716) is what you're after.

Comment: For that I could create a ValidationAttribute and also keep it in the Data Layer. My purpose is to not define it in the Data Layer.

Comment: So you should create viewmodel for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation attributes is not part of Entity Framework. 
If you want splite data layer from presentation layer, you can use Viewmodels and bind them on datamodels with Automapper. In this case you place domain validation on viewmodel and validation of datalayer on datamodel.
In very complicated cases you may have three models: viewmodel, domainmodel and datamodel, but in common cases viewmodel and datamodel is enough.

Comment: We are going to revise either we mantain the Data Layer and create ViewModels or stick together the Domain and Data Layer.